# 5x5 Grid with all two digit numbers

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

There is a $5\times5$ grid where you are supposed to put all two digit numbers which consist only of the digits $1$ to $5$, namely $11,12,13,14,15$,$21,22$,....

The task is to put all these two digit numbers into the grid such that horizontally or vertically there has to be at most two of each digit.

> Is it possible? If not, what is the maximum amount of distinct two-digit numbers you can put?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose we:

> Swapped the tens digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for A, B, C, D, E

Then the task becomes:

> Make two latin squares such that when placed on top of each other each ordered pair of values appears only once (as @JaapScherphius points out, this is called a [Graeco-Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square))

And we can do this:

> ```
> A1 B2 C3 D4 E5
> B5 C1 D2 E3 A4
> C4 D5 E1 A2 B3
> D3 E4 A5 B1 C2
> E2 A3 B4 C5 D1
> ```

Converting back, we have:

> ```
> 11 22 33 44 55
> 25 31 42 53 14
> 34 45 51 12 23
> 43 54 15 21 32
> 52 13 24 35 41
> ```

NB:

> A 6x6 grid wouldn't be possible via this particular method, neither would a 2x2 grid, but everything else would be

Comment: is this question something asked before? I thought it was my original to be honest :))) you solved it too fast.

Comment: @Oray I haven't heard of a similar question, but my experiences in mathematics have taught me to try simplifying the problem, which worked in this case.

Comment: does it related to 5x5 magic square?

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati nope, not even close.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thanks, had forgotten the name